# What causes Autonumbering to stop working after "Evaluating" Notebook in 12.0

Tags: bugs, front-end, notebooks, stylesheet

**Bug introduced in 12.0**

---

I'm using "Section" autonumbering in a notebook that contains text and calculations. Normally my "Section" style numbering looks like:

```
1) 
2) 
3)
```

After evaluating the notebook the "Section" style numbering looks like:

```
0)
0)
0)
```

Nothing I have tried corrects the problem. I have tried stopping and restarting the kernel. I have tried unloading and reloading the style sheet. When I execute:

```
CurrentValue[{"CounterValue", "Section"}]
```

the command returns zero even though prior to executing the command I initiated 3 "Section" command. I get the same type of failure if I use the default stylesheet and the "ItemNumbered" style.

If I exit *Mathematica* and reopen it all the sections are numbered correctly. Also if I open another notebook it autonumbers correctly.  The problem is localized to any notebook that has been evaluated with the notebook evaluation command.

This problem doesn't happen with 11.3, only 12.0. Anyone know how to correct the problem in the evaluated notebook?

Comment: Maybe you can create a small notebook that exhibits the issue, and then evaluate `NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]]` and include the output.

Comment: I am seeing a similar problem. I have a series of ItemNumbered cells whose numbers have changed to 0. I cannot change them back with the Options Inspector. I can get correctly numbered cells in a new notebook, but when they are copied into the bad notebook the become all zeros. I have not explicitly done a notebook evaluation although I have evaluated some of the (non ItemNumbered) cells in the notebook.

Comment: @CarlWoll The code of problematic Notebook won't help, because the problem disappears after saving and reopening the Notebook. Please see my answer for the steps which allow to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have enclosed the output of a notebook that exhibits the problem. The 1 and 2 were generated using "ItemNumbered". After "Evaluation > Evaluate Nootbook", I get 0 everytime I use "ItemNumbered".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: the bug is confirmed by WRI tech support, [CASE:4338353].

---

I reproduce the issue with version 12.0 on Windows 7 x64. Here are the steps:

1. In a new (empty) Notebook apply the `Evaluation ► Evaluate Notebook` menu item.
2. Now create a new `"ItemNumbered"` cell by applying the `Format ► Style ► ItemNumbered` menu item.

Here is the result:

[image: screenshot 1]

After saving this Notebook and reopening the numbering works correctly:

[image: screenshot 2]

Now apply the `Evaluation ► Evaluate Notebook` menu item again, put the cursor after the first cell, and then apply the  `Format ► Style ► ItemNumbered` menu item. Here is the result:

[image: screenshot 3]

With the above method the issue reliably reproduces on my machine with version 12.0. With version 11.3 everything works as expected, so the bug seemingly is introduced in version 12.0.